# Creating a Windows Screensaver with Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I recently made a cool Three.JS program, and I was wondering if there is a way to convert it into a windows screensaver.

You can see the application [here](http://mjkaufer.github.io/3DIG/). Naturally, I'd plan on removing things like the input fields if it were to become an actual screensaver. I'm just curious if there is any way to make a Three.JS application into a windows screensaver.

Thanks.

Comment: Three.js is a browser-based system. Windows screensavers are actually exectuable programs (e.g. `.exe` files) that happen to use `.scr` as their extension. Unless you've got something that can compile JS+browser down into an executable, you can't use it as a screensaver.

Comment: there are a couple free tools to convert a webpage into a windows screensaver, google is your friend. i think they all use IE to render.

Comment: I was wondering moreso how to program one on my own. It looks like .NET has a javascript compiler, so I'll look into @MarcB's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a WinForm project with a Browser control that load your html document.
Compile it to get an exe file and install as screensaver